# JavaScript, can't make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This HTML makes site background change it color by pressing button and change it background image by pressing image. But I don't know how to make text link instead of image that will change background image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <style type="text/css">
 body{
   background: no-repeat;
 }

  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
     function change_color(obj)
     {
       obj.value && (document.body.style.backgroundColor = obj.value);
       obj.src && (document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+obj.src+')');
     }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="1.php" onsubmit="return false">
 <button class="color" id="red" name="button" value="red" onclick='change_color(this)'>red</button>
 <button class="color" id="orange" name="button" value="orange" onclick='change_color(this)'>orange</button>
    <img src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/ca_serenity/misc/logo.gif" alt="" onclick='change_color(this)'>
    <img src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/smilies/victory.gif" alt="" onclick='change_color(this)'>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `text link` ?

Comment: Are you just asking how to make a link in HTML?  What did you find when you looked up exactly that?

Comment: Change `<img src=".."/ onclick="..">` to `<span onclick="change_color(this)">text here</span>`

Comment: @freedomn-m why are you using `onclick` when the OP has tagged jQuery ?? You need to correct him

Comment: @mrid I disagree.  There's no jquery in the question, you'll no doubt have found from your *own* experience on SO that people asking questions just click on whatever tags they think might be relevant.  In this case, it would be prudent to *remove* the jquery tag, not lean to it.  Any answer should match the mode of the question (in this case using onclick).  An *extra* could be "you can do this way better" - but it should not be the *only* answer as you imply.  Also, it's a **comment** not an answer.

Comment: @mrid further to the above, adding an answer that says "as it's tagged jquery, here's a jquery answer" is also a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the `src` as a custom attribute `data-src`, and set `href="#"` to avoid navigation when user clicks on the link.

```
<a href="#" data-src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/smilies/victory.gif" onclick="change_color(this)">Smiley</a>
```

Then you can add the following in your click handler to get the image location, and update it on the DOM:

```
obj.attributes["data-src"] && (document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + obj.attributes["data-src"].value + ')');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function change_color(obj) {
      obj.value && (document.body.style.backgroundColor = obj.value);
      obj.src && (document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + obj.src + ')');
      
      obj.attributes["data-src"] && (document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + obj.attributes["data-src"].value + ')');
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="1.php" onsubmit="return false">
    <button class="color" id="red" name="button" value="red" onclick='change_color(this)'>red</button>
    <button class="color" id="orange" name="button" value="orange" onclick='change_color(this)'>orange</button>
    <a  href="#" data-src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/ca_serenity/misc/logo.gif" onclick="change_color(this)">Logo</a>
    <a href="#" data-src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/smilies/victory.gif" onclick="change_color(this)">Smiley</a>
    <img src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/ca_serenity/misc/logo.gif" alt="" onclick='change_color(this)'>
    <img src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/smilies/victory.gif" alt="" onclick='change_color(this)'>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged jQuery in the question, here's the jQuery equivalent of your code:

```
<a href="#_" class="change-color" data-color="red">Change Color</a>
```

js:

```
$('.change-color').click(function(){
    $(document).css({'background': $(this).data('color')});
});
```

Comment: gave you a +1 for a much neater (ie jquery...) answer

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a text based hyperlink? e.g.

```
<a href="#_" onclick="change_color(this)">Change Color</a>
```

Comment: I doubt that alone would be enough, as the event handler is trying to get `src` or `value` property. Since none of them are set on the `a`, it won't work.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't spot that the function itself had dependencies like that. The answer by @mrid would make much more sense then.